# Finding the norm of $w + \frac{1 - |w|^2}{|w - z|^2}(w - z)$, where $w$ and $z$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

I'm trying to show a result from Manfred Stoll's book on Hyperbolic geometry. Consider the function 
$$M_w(z) = w + \frac{1 - |w|^2}{|w - z|^2}(w - z)$$ where $w,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $|w| < 1$. (I am using different variable names than Stoll). This function generalizes the Möbius transformations on the complex numbers.

Stoll writes that 
$$|M_w(z)|^2 = \frac{|w - z|^2 + (1 - |w|^2)(1-|z|^2)}{|w - z|^2}$$ 
How do you show this? I tried computing $\langle M_w(z), M_w(z) \rangle$, but I'm not getting any closer.

This result ultimately shows that $M_w(z)$ maps into the unit ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\left|M_w(z)\right|^2 &=
|w|^2+\frac{\left(1-|w|^2\right)^2}{|w-z|^4}|w-z|^2+2\frac{1-|w|^2}{|w-z|^2}\;w\cdot(w-z) \\[8pt]
|w-z|^2\;\left|M_w(z)\right|^2 &=
|w|^2|w-z|^2+\left(1-|w|^2\right)^2+2\left(1-|w|^2\right)\;\left(|w|^2-w\cdot z\right) \\[8pt]
&=
\phantom{+2}|w|^2\left(|w|^2+|z|^2-2w\cdot z\right)\\
&\phantom{=}+\phantom{2}\left(1-2|w|^2+|w|^4\right)\\
&\phantom{=}+2\left(|w|^2-w\cdot z-|w|^4+|w|^2w\cdot z \right) \\[8pt]
&=
\left(-2w\cdot z\right)+ \left(1 + |w|^2|z|^2\right)\\[6pt]
&=
\left(|w|^2+|z|^2-2w\cdot z\right)+ \left(1 -|w|^2-|z|^2+ |w|^2|z|^2\right)\\[6pt]
&=
|w-z|^2+ \left(1 -|w|^2\right)\left(1-|z|^2\right)\\
\end{align}$$